# Updating plotly-js Y axis with dynamic input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plotly, plotly.js

I am making a dynamic chart from `CSV` data using [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/) The `x-axis` is the number of rows in the file and the `y-axis` shows dataset selectable via `dropdown` with two options:

- `data 1`
- `data 2`

Both options represent column `values` in the file. When I choose `data 1` the `y-axis` takes `values` from that column and the graph is shown, the same for `data 2`.

The problem is that when `data 1` is selected and plotted, selecting `data 2` adds new data (new line) to the chart without clearing the previous one. I want the line of `data 1` to disappear when `data 2` is selected. Can someone help me here and tell me how should I achieve this functionality?

```
    function selectedY() {
      var axisValue = $("#dataBtn :selected").val();

      Plotly.d3.csv(result.csv, function(allRows){
       var x_row = [], y_data = [];
       for (var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
          xrow = i;
          row = allRows[i];
          x_row.push( xrow);
          y_data.push( +row[axisValue]);

        var dataRow = {
            x: x_row,
            y: y_data,
            mode: 'lines+markers',
            type: 'scatter',
            line: {
              color: '#62B5E5',
              width: 2
            }
          };

          var data =[dataRow];

          var layout= {
          title: dynamic chart
          };

          Plotly.plot("chart", data, layout);    
      });
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <select class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow btn-round" onchange="selectedY()" data-style="btn-dark" style="right: 10px; top: 20px;" id="dataBtn" title="Choose data">
     <option value="" disabled>Choose options</option>
     <option value="1" disabled>Data 1</option>
     <option value="2" disabled>Data 0</option>
    </select>

    <div id="chart" style="width: 1050px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

You can clear the "old" line using `restyle` function. Also you don't need to load your CSV file each time you call the function. In addition I had to fix some syntax errors in your example (e.g. missing quotes in `title: dynamic chart`, etc...)

I didn't have your data so I used an online source but I tried to leave most of your original code untouched in this example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>

<select onchange="selectedY()"  style="right: 10px; top: 20px;" id="dataBtn" title="Choose data">
     <option value="">Choose options</option>
     <option value="Number of Solar Plants">Number of Solar Plants</option>
     <option value="Installed Capacity (MW)">Installed Capacity</option>
     <option value="Generation (GWh)">Generation</option>
</select>

<div id="chart" style="width: 1050px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script>

    var data = [];
    var layout= {title: 'Solar Energy', 'xaxis': {'title': 'States'}, };
    var allRows = null

    Plotly.d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv', function(err, data){
        allRows = data
    }); 

    Plotly.plot("chart", data, layout); 

    function selectedY() {
    var axisValue = $("#dataBtn :selected").val();

      var x_row = [], y_data = [];

      for (var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
        xrow = i;
        row = allRows[i];
        x_row.push(xrow);
        y_data.push(+row[axisValue]);

        var dataRow = {
            x: x_row,
            y: y_data,
            mode: 'lines+markers',
            type: 'scatter',
            line: {
              color: '#62B5E5',
              width: 2
            }
         }; 
      }  

      layout['yaxis'] = {'title': {'text': axisValue}}
      Plotly.restyle('chart', 'y', [[]]); 
      Plotly.plot("chart", [dataRow], layout);        
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me here with this solution but I am having another issue when I try to print dataRow in the console it says undefined, I believe the data is not being parsed in allRows